# Fitting series to a distribution

Tags: time-series, distributions, finance, fitting

I am reading [this note](http://corporate.morningstar.com/ib/documents/MethodologyDocuments/IBBAssociates/CVarOptimization.pdf) on Mean-CVAR optimization. The authors argue against the prevailing assumption that asset classes are normally distributed and propose using a truncated levy flight distribution to describe the behavior of asset classes.

Now, here is my comprehension of fitting a historical time series to a new distribution, please kindly correct me if my thinking is wrong.

1. You determine what parameters are needed for your new distribution: In the case of the levy flight distribution, you require the tail index, a skewness parameter, a scale parameter and a location parameter
2. You estimate those parameters from your historical time series: In this case, the tail index is estimated as Kurtosis, the skewness parameter is estimated as historical skewness, the scale parameter as standard deviation and the location parameter as the historical average.
3. You simulate your new variables by applying your estimates to the inverse of the cumulative distribution function of the levy flight distribution.  **Can someone explain how this is done?**

More questions:

- Once you fit a new distribution, does that imply that your old estimates are no longer relevant?
- What are some good ways to test for the goodness of fit for a levy flight distribution?